# How can probability variables of different dimensions share the same parameter in VAE?

Tags: probability, distributions, autoencoders

I am confused while studying VAE(Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes).

**My problem is as follows:**

We have a continuous variable $x$ and a random variable $z$.

The dimensions of $x$ and $z$ are different, with $x$ typically representing an image.

The $z$ is generated from some prior distribution $p_{\theta^*}(z)$.

And the $x$ is generated from some conditional distribution $p_{\theta^*}(x|z)$.

How can probability variables of different dimensions ($x, y$) share the same parameter $\theta$?

Is there a cue in the reparameterization trick?